# Explain relative paths - VWD vs IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone breifly explain how c# treats paths - or perhaps the development environment and VWD (that is not acting as I think a server should)?

I have a page: `/content/consumer/MyPage.aspx`.  My images are all in `/images`.

When I put `src="/images/myimage.jpg"` or `src="\images\myimage.jpg"` why am I not seeing my images?  If I put `../../images/myimage.jpg` or `..\..\images\myimage.jpg`, I can see it or if I make it a server control and use `src="~/images/myimage.jpg` or `src="~\images\myimage.jpg` (at which point it changes it to the previous).  What happened to my being able to just refer to the root by starting my path with a slash?  Am I being forced to make all these controls run at the server (which seems like a waste of resources) or be stuck with declarative paths and messy nests of ..(/|)s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain your path is `/content/consumer/MyPage.aspx` and not something like `/<projectname>/content/consumer/MyPage.aspx`?

By default, Visual Studio / VWD will use a base path `/<projectname>/`; however, if you'd like no base path, you can open the project's *Properties*, go to the tab *Web* and enter "`/`" for *virtual path*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a resource.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Comment: I think this link would be really useful for someone needing to grasp Absolute and Relative Paths.  Doesn't really address how c# and vwd treat paths.  Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

If you start your reference with a "/", it is relative to the root directory of your website as seen by IIS.

If you start your reference with a "~", it's relative to the application (virtual directory) as seen by IIS.  This can be different than the "/" if your web site is a subdirectory of another virtual directory.

If you don't start it with either of those, then it's relative to the directory that the file resides in.